# Gateaux Differentiability and Frechet Differentiability in Infinite Dimensional Separable Hilbert Space.

Tags: functional-analysis

We are familiar with the fact that in classical Euclidean space, the existence of continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability. A natural question is how different this is in an Infinite Dimensional Separable Hilbert Space.

Is there a function $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a separable Hilbert space $H$ such that:

(1): For each $x\in H$, we have that $f$ has a bounded linear Gateaux differential $\left( Df\left( x\right)  \right)  \left( h\right)  $ at $x$.

(2): There exists an $M>0$, such that for all $x,y\in H$, it holds that $$\left| f\left( x\right)  -f\left( y\right)  \right|  \leqslant M\left| \left| x-y\right|  \right| .$$

(3): For all $h\in H$, we have that $H\rightarrow \mathbb{R} ,x\mapsto \left( Df\left( x\right)  \right)  \left( h\right)  $ is a continuous function.

(4): There is a $x_{0}\in H$, such that $f$ is not Frechet Differentiable at $x_{0}$?